# Is this a transistor emitter follower circuit?

Tags: transistors, emitter-follower

I saw this kind of circuit in an IC block diagram.

It looks like an emitter follower circuit, but the collector is not connected with Vcc (not higher than base.)

What is Vout?

Where would this kind of circuit be used?
[image: circuit]

Comment: it's diode connecd so the transistor behaves as a diode.

Comment: An emitter follower would have a **power supply** which your circuit does not have. Use a web search to search for "emitter follower circuit" to see examples of a proper emitter follower circuit.

Comment: You can add in a legible schematic using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a transistor connected as a diode when base and collector are connectes together.

It's most often used measuring temperatures due to the predictability and linearity of the PN semiconductor junction.

Comment: I changed the circuit.  In this case. Why is transistor used instead of general doide or zener? For temperature stability??

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a diode-connected transistor with Vf much lower than when using the junctions alone.

The same effect would be obtained with the base and emitter interconnected.

With a diode-connected germanium transistor, Vf could be as low as 0.1V.

Here's such an application for a crystal radio.

[image]

The purpose of a diode connected transistor in the OP's circuit is not clear.